# Switching between one QToolButton to another in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I want to switch from one `QToolButton` to another in `QToolBar`. I have used `QStackedWidget`, their it is too simple to move from one `widget` to other but here I am not able to get how to move via using `keyReleaseEvent`.

```
mywindow::mywindow() : QMainWindow()
{   
    widget = new QWidget();
    setCentralWidget(widget);

    tool = new QToolBar();
    vertical = new QVBoxLayout();
    button1 = new QToolButton();
    connect( button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(fileNew()) );

    button2 = new QToolButton();
    button3 = new QToolButton();

    button1->setIcon(QIcon("download.jpg"));
    button1->setGeometry(0,0,100,200);
    button2->setIcon(QIcon("images.jpg"));
    button3->setIcon(QIcon("settings-icon.jpg"));

    //stack1->addWidget(button1);
    //stack1->addWidget(button2);
    //stack1->addWidget(button3);

    tool->addWidget(button1);
    tool->addWidget(button2);
    tool->addWidget(button3);
    //tool->addWidget(stack1);

    vertical->addWidget(tool);
    widget->setLayout(vertical);
}

void mywindow::keyReleaseEvent(KeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case:Qt::Key_Left:


    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to add buttons to the tool bar with ` QToolBar::addAction()`?

Comment: ok i will add buttons using addAction. But how to navigate from one button to other?

Comment: For navigation, or triggering particular button you can assign a shortcut to each of them with `QAction::setShortcut()` function.

Comment: I dont want to add shortcut. I want to navigate by using KeyReleaseEvent

Comment: Well, than handle key events in the QToolBar or QMainWindow subclass.

Comment: That what i am asking. How exactly to navigate while pressing KeyLeft key.. What should i write

Comment: Clarify what`s the problem? Do you want to know how to switch between buttons without QStackedWidget? Well, then you could just hide every button except the active one. Or you want to know how to do it while key pressed, or what?

Comment: It's called focus. e.g. `if (button1->hasFocus()) { button2->setFocus(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check against the focus, and shift that as appropriate. I would write something like this:

```
void mywindow::keyReleaseEvent(KeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case:Qt::Key_Left:
            if (button3->hasFocus())
                button2->setFocus();
            else if (button2->hasFocus())
                button1->setFocus();
            break;
        case:Qt::Key_Right:
            if (button1->hasFocus())
                button2->setFocus();
            else if (button2->hasFocus())
                button3->setFocus();
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that this code can go tedious easily if you keep adding further buttons. I would place them into a container. Then, I would iterate through that container forward and reverse order depending on the focus switching logic.

See the documentation for further details:

> [focus : const bool](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qwidget.html#focus-prop)
>
> This property holds whether this widget (or its focus proxy) has the keyboard input focus.
>
> By default, this property is false.
>
> Note: Obtaining the value of this property for a widget is effectively equivalent to checking whether QApplication::focusWidget() refers to the widget.
>
> Access functions:
> bool  hasFocus() const

Comment: Now automatically it is shifting two times when pressing one time Key_left or Key_Right. How to control it?